# ReactJs and NodeJs JSON parser issue. app.use(bodyParser.json) seems not working

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm a beginner of ReactJs, NodeJs, express, etc and all the Javascript things. I'm trying the following code sample to learn the basics.

My issue is when I commented out the following line

```
app.use(bodyParser.json);
```

I can see the returning data. But if uncomment it back data will not appear. Anyway, the returning data is coming as an object array as below.

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

How can parse the JSON to see the actual data?
Do I really need to specify following two lines to get JSON data? if so, how to do it?

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
```

Following is the full code

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

var client = new Client();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json);

app.post('/api',(req,res)=>{

client.get("https://url", function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object
    console.log("DATA : "+data);
    res.json({msg:true,data:data});

    // raw response
    //console.log("RESPONSE: "+response);
 });

 });

app.listen(3001,()=>{
console.log("listning to port 3001");
 })
```

Here is the dependency versions as in the package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"cors": "^2.8.4",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"node-rest-client": "^3.1.0"
```

}

Highly appreciate your feedback

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json());` You forgot the `()` which actually invokes the function in order to set up the middleware.

Comment: oh yeah! I missed that. Thanks, @Neil Lunn  Now it returns the data even with that line enabled but still shows the object array instead of actual data

Comment: The reason behind showing object array is because I have console.log it with a String concatenation eg: console.log("Data" + result) which converts the return json results to a string. the correct way of putting it should be console.log("Data",result)

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this my friend

```
app.post('/api',(req,res)=>{

client.get("https://url", function (data, response) {

    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({msg:true,data:req.body});


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

You need to use it like this

```
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

You are using

```
app.use(bodyParser.json)
```

Where you have missed ()